# Getting data from another page using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

Good morning everyone. I tried creating a site that could get information from another page and feed the response into a div tag, but it didnt work. I checked with a very similar one i learnt from. Here is the HTML code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function checkit(){
var samxml; var username;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
samxml = new XMLHttpRequest();}
else  {
samxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

samxml.onreadystatechange = function() {

if (samxml.readyState == 4 && samxml.status == 200){
document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = samxml.responseText;}
}
username = document.getElementById("username").value;
samxml.open("POST", "check.php",true);

samxml.send( "username" );



}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label for ="username">User ID:</label>
<input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username"/>


<div id = "check"></div>
<button type = "button" onclick = "checkit()">Check</button>
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP page:

```
//php file
<?php
$user = $_POST["username"];
if ($user == "samuel") {
echo "Hmm. Chosen! Choose another one";}
else {
echo "Nice one";}
?>
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? Can you see an AJAX request being sent at all?

Comment: I can see a change in UrL. One of the errors one of the times was my variable in the php script was not declared or something.